# How does Python manage to loop through values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, python-3.7, dictionary-comprehension

I want to know how Python loops through values in a dictionary. I know how to do it in code, and all of the answers I have read just explain how to do it. 
I want to understand how python finds the values, as I thought that dictionary values were associated with keys. Do dictionary items also have an index value or something?
Thanks for the answers or references to a relevant source in advance :)

I've Googled, stackoverflowed, and read.

edit: I'm interested in how Python3.7 achieves this

Comment: Internally, I imagine dictionary items are kept in a linked list.  So iterating over values just boils down to traversing a linked list.  But this is a very low-level detail, completely hidden from the programmer, and could differ widely across various Python implementations.

Comment: This excellent [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p33CVV29OG8) by core Python developer Raymond Hettinger explains how dictionaries have been implemented in various versions of Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code ([`dict_items(PyDictObject *mp)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2232)) a list of n (size # of key/value pairs in the dictionary) tuples is allocated, and for each non-null value item (line 2278: `if (value != NULL)`), it is set at the corresponding index of the tuple list.
The python object itself is basically a chunk of memory that knows the size of each object (`offset`), and where the values start (`value_ptr`), and where the keys are (`ep`). So when you get the keys/values (`for k,v in object`) it basically did an entire traversal through the used up portion of the allocated memory for the object.

Btw, it may help to know PyList_SET_ITEM is just a macro to set the value in an array by its desired index: [`#define PyList_SET_ITEM(op, i, v) (((PyListObject *)(op))->ob_item\[i\] = (v))`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Include/listobject.h#L73). Since arrays are just values stored sequentially in memory, the index operator knows to place the value at memory location of `start + (sizeOf(object)*index)`.

Disclaimer: This is the first time I've tried reading the python source code so my interpretation may be a bit off, or oversimplified.

Comment: Despite the name, `dict_items` is not actually used by `dict.items()` or any dict methods. Dict iteration is lower down, in the iterator/view code.

Comment: Also, unlike what John Gordon said, linked lists aren't involved at any point in the process.

Comment: Was more so giving an example of how Python iterates through keys/values. I saw a lot of pointer manipulation going on throughout the core functions and this seemed like one of the more readable/easier to understand methods. I don't think the "for key,value in object" (which is probably the most common way of iterating through an object/dictionary) would be executed/implemented in a completely different way - but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: None of the list stuff happens in actual iteration over a dict.